# Is there a prevent the input clear when using material-ui TextField with datetime-local type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks

If execute the code below and enter only date, the rendering process will run and the date input will clear.

This TextField is intended to be used as a search condition for this component.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

export const App = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
    const [date, setDate] = React.useState()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const handle = setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(true);
            // do something fetch.
            setLoading(false);
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearTimeout(handle);
    }, [loading]);

    return (
        <div>
            <TextField type='datetime-local' onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)} defaultValue={date} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Input was kept when changing render to the following.

```
<input type='datetime-local' onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)} />
```

Is there a way to keep the date entered using material-ui?

Thank you!

Comment: not sure is this you need https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e6jjv9 ? check this once ! and not sure what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to do [stackblitz.com/edit/react-vcxvfw](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vcxvfw). Please check the difference between TextField and input.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do.Thank you!

Comment: I want to your comment to be this answer. Can you rewrite it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the initial value to `TextField` component and it should have a value prop like below:

```
<TextField
    type="datetime-local"
    InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
    }}
    value={date}
    onChange={(e) => { setDate(e.target.value) } }
/>
```

If you're wondering why we need to have this , look at the below example:

```
class SampleApp extends Component {
  state = {
    date : "" // setting initial state date as ""
  }

  render() {
    return  <TextField
          type="datetime-local"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
          value={this.state.date}
          onChange={(e) => { this.setState({date : e.target.value}) } }
        />
  }
}
```

In class components, We set initialValue of date state is "".

So In your functional component you have to do like below:

```
const App2 = () => {

  //if you need to set initialvalues to muliple do this
  const initialVal = {
    date: '',
    dateField2: ''
  }

  const [{date, dateField2}, setDate] = React.useState(initialVal); // need to set here // setting initial state date as ""

  return <TextField
          type="datetime-local"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
          value={date}
          onChange={(e) => { setDate(e.target.value) } }
        />
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e6jjv9), Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the easy-to-understand answer.